# Selecting data range for chart

Tags: vba, excel

Currently having trouble with some code, I am trying to select the source data for a chart from a macro I have created:

```
  With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Info").ChartObjects("Speed").Activate

    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Log").Range("A5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("C5").Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
End With
```

I am returning "Unable to get the Select property of the Range class".

I need to be able to get the source data starting from "A5" and going down to the last piece of data (will vary), this is the same for "C5".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log")
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info").ChartObjects("Speed").Chart _
         .SetSourceData Source:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range(.Cells(5,1), _
         .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlup).Row, 3))
End With
```